# Where is the critical location for warrior?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am fighting the warrior right now, and as with some YouTube videos I have seen, the critical location for it is where the warrior's stomach is.

However, whenever I aim there, it never gives me a critical. Is there a specific spot or any gun requirement for getting the critical on warrior?

Comment: What type of weapons are you using against it? Certain weapons and affect combinations cannot deal criticals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

His crit spots are his Heart, his mouth and his...ribs? on his sides.

Here he his with a hole in his heart, taking some crit damage:

[image]

I tried to get a good pic of his ribs/side weak spot but they didn't come out clearly.

All crit spots save for the mouth are covered by hard, destructible rock; they're pretty noticable and just scream "weak point". Keep shooting them and they'll break, showing liquid lava underneath. All of his crit points are lava. His mouth isn't armored, but it's much harder to hit as it's always moving and nor always in an easy to shoot spot. I think, but I'm not sure, that his mouth takes more damage from shots than his heart. A good sniper can get a few good hits in there, but otherwise I wouldn't recommend it.

Note that the armor covering his heart and arm weakpoints regenerates every time he goes in the lava, which he does after taking so much damage. After you break the armor over his heart he'll go back under the level soon, so be quick. If you're precise and break just one chunk of armor and keep hitting the weak spot you'll have more time to deal critical damage than if you break *all* the armor around his heart, so be precise if at all possible.

Not some weapons like rocket launchers and other splash-damage weapons won't crit. Try a sniper rifle to confirm that you're getting crits. If your weapon isn't capable of getting critical hits, I recommend switching to one which can. Warrior takes significantly reduced damage anywhere but his crit spots, and even direct hits on his weak spots with non-crit damage won't hurt him much.

Comment: I always just aimed for his mouth, who knew he had more than one spot :P

Comment: Aren't the eyes weak spots, too?

Comment: @Strike I don't think so, and if they're are they're by far the worst target to pick. I tried for a few minutes to hit him in the eye and the only crits I got were from accidentally shooting him in the mouth

Comment: Doesn't matter where you hit it, just hit it...
After a certain amount of damage of using some explosion type weapon, the stomach opens up. The guy is just too easy...

Answer (score -2):

This will take some time and a lot of ammo but it works. The only spot where The Warrior cannot hit you is at the shrine outside the main battlefield. Once there take out a weapon with the explosive element (preferably an assault rifle) then blast away at the glowing heart on its chest!